# rake migration aborted: error with uninitialized constant and migration naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rake

I've searched through stackoverflow and don't see a similar problem. I'm trying to add one column into the existing Slicks table. Should be easy enough but I'm pulling my hair out!
I might have not named the rails command for migration well enough: rails generate migration AddNametoSlicks name:string

Also:
1.) this command generated this migration 20130605194117_add_nameto_slicks.rb
which did not look right without _. I changed the name of the migration to add_name_to_slicks.rb

2.) The migration command did not generate the add_column. What am I missing on the command?

Here's the migration file:

```
class AddNametoSlicks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :slicks, :name, :string
  end
end
```

Error from terminal:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant AddNameToSlicks/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_su
pport/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `eac
h'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `con
stantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:5
4:in `constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:538:in `load_migratio
n'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:533:in `migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 leve
ls) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_
transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/datab
ase_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transactio
n'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transacti
on'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migr
ate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:179:in `bl
ock (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_leve
l'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gigbase/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AddNameToSlicks is being requested but you have AddNametoSlicks.

Change to - To

Comment: Super! Thanks for catching that. It worked - the column was added in schema.rb. I'll try to like your comment, but since I'm new, it hasn't been letting me!